# Web API + ODataQueryOptions + $top or $skip is causing a SqlException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This code has been simplified for this example.

The query is actually returned from a service, which is why I would prefer to write the method this way.

```c#
[HttpGet]
public PageResult<ExceptionLog> Logging(ODataQueryOptions<ExceptionLog> options)
{
    var query = from o in _exceptionLoggingService.entities.ExceptionDatas
                select new ExceptionLog {
                    ExceptionDataId = o.ExceptionDataId,
                    SiteId = o.SiteId,
                    ExceptionDateTime = o.ExceptionDateTime,
                    StatusCode = o.StatusCode,
                    Url = o.Url,
                    ExceptionType = o.ExceptionType,
                    ExceptionMessage = o.ExceptionMessage,
                    Exception = o.Exception,
                    RequestData = o.RequestData
                };

    var results = options.ApplyTo(query) as IEnumerable<ExceptionLog>;
    var count = results.LongCount();

    return new PageResult<ExceptionLog>(results, Request.GetNextPageLink(), count);
}
```

The above code errors on "results.LongCount()" with the following Exception:

```
SqlException: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.
```

It appears that I'm getting an exception with when trying to page, like this "$top=2".  Everything works fine if my querystring is like this "$filter=ExceptionDataId gt 100".

Since ExceptionData (the Entity) matches ExceptionLog (business model) I can do something like this as a workaround:

```c#
[HttpGet]
public PageResult<ExceptionLog> Logging(ODataQueryOptions<ExceptionData> options)
{
    var query = from o in _exceptionLoggingService.entities.ExceptionDatas
                orderby o.ExceptionDateTime descending
                select o;

    var results = from o in options.ApplyTo(query) as IEnumerable<ExceptionData>
                    select new ExceptionLog {
                        ExceptionDataId = o.ExceptionDataId,
                        SiteId = o.SiteId,
                        ExceptionDateTime = o.ExceptionDateTime,
                        StatusCode = o.StatusCode,
                        Url = o.Url,
                        ExceptionType = o.ExceptionType,
                        ExceptionMessage = o.ExceptionMessage,
                        Exception = o.Exception,
                        RequestData = o.RequestData
                    };

    return new PageResult<ExceptionLog>(results, Request.GetNextPageLink(), results.LongCount());
}
```

But this doesn't completely work for me because it's a little hackish and I can't use the service's method which already gives me an IQueryable.

Another thing to note, is if the Logging method is converted to IQueryable, everything works correctly.  But I need to return the Count with the query so I have to return a PageResult.

Answer (score 5):

This is the workaround I'm using.  I only apply the filter from the ODataQueryOptions and I manually apply the Top and Skip.

First I created some extension methods:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace System.Web.Http.OData.Query
{
    public static class ODataQuerySettingsExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, ODataQueryOptions<T> options)
        {
            if (options.Filter == null)
            {
                return query;
            }

            return options.Filter.ApplyTo(query, new ODataQuerySettings()) as IEnumerable<T>;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> ApplyTopAndTake<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, ODataQueryOptions<T> options)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> value = query;

            if (options.Top != null)
            {
                value = value.Take(options.Top.Value);
            }

            if (options.Skip != null)
            {
                value = value.Skip(options.Skip.Value);
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my method looks like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public PageResult<ExceptionLog> Logging(ODataQueryOptions<ExceptionLog> options)
{
    // GetLogs returns an IQueryable<ExceptionLog> as seen in Question above.
    var query = _exceptionLoggingService.GetLogs()
                                        .ApplyFilter(options);
    var count = query.Count();
    var results = query.ApplyTopAndTake(options);

    return new PageResult<ExceptionLog>(results, Request.GetNextPageLink(), count);
}
```